# makefile move command make it do not work

Tags: makefile

I write a makefile to run hadoop in Ubuntu. When the `inputs`command is follow `run:`, it works. But if I move it down to the below of `hdfs dfs -rm -f -r $(EXAMPLE_DIR)`, it failed and shows the error message : 
`make: inputs: Command not found.`I am new to Ubuntu so I do not know how to fix the problem after searching the result because this error has too many possible causes. The makefile is showed below. I mark the part which confuse me.

```
   EXAMPLE_DIR = /user/$(USER)/matmult-dense/
    INPUT_DIR   = $(EXAMPLE_DIR)/input
    OUTPUT_DIR  = $(EXAMPLE_DIR)/output
    OUTPUT_FILE = $(OUTPUT_DIR)/part-00000
    HADOOP_VERSION = 2.6.0
    # generally I use HADOOP_HOME, for not modifying the original makefile, I set up the HADOOP_PREFIX here
    HADOOP_PREFIX = /usr/local/hadoop

    TOOLLIBS_DIR=$(HADOOP_PREFIX)/share/hadoop/tools/lib/
    //Hi, start here
    run: inputs
        hdfs dfs -rm -f -r $(EXAMPLE_DIR)
   //Hi, end here. If swap them, the error comes        
        hadoop jar $(TOOLLIBS_DIR)/hadoop-streaming-$(HADOOP_VERSION).jar \
            -files ./map1.py,./reduce1.py \
            -mapper ./map1.py \
            -reducer ./reduce1.py \
            -input $(INPUT_DIR) \
            -output  $(OUTPUT_DIR) \
            -numReduceTasks 1 \
            -jobconf stream.num.map.output.key.fields=5 \
            -jobconf stream.map.output.field.separator='\t' \
            -jobconf mapreduce.partition.keypartitioner.options=-k1,3
        hdfs dfs -rm $(INPUT_DIR)/file01
        hdfs dfs -mv $(OUTPUT_FILE) $(INPUT_DIR)/file01
        hdfs dfs -rm -f -r $(OUTPUT_DIR)
        hadoop jar $(TOOLLIBS_DIR)/hadoop-streaming-$(HADOOP_VERSION).jar \
            -files ./map2.py,./reduce2.py \
            -mapper ./map2.py \
            -reducer ./reduce2.py \
            -input $(INPUT_DIR) \
            -output  $(OUTPUT_DIR) \
            -numReduceTasks 1 \
            -jobconf stream.num.map.output.key.fields=2 \
            -jobconf stream.map.output.field.separator='\t'
        hdfs dfs -cat $(OUTPUT_FILE)

    directories:
        hdfs dfs -test -e $(EXAMPLE_DIR) || hdfs dfs -mkdir $(EXAMPLE_DIR)
        hdfs dfs -test -e $(INPUT_DIR) || hdfs dfs -mkdir $(INPUT_DIR)
        hdfs dfs -test -e $(OUTPUT_DIR) || hdfs dfs -mkdir $(OUTPUT_DIR)

    inputs: directories 
        hdfs dfs -test -e $(INPUT_DIR)/file01 \
        || hdfs dfs -put matrices $(INPUT_DIR)/file01

    clean:
        hdfs dfs -rm -f -r $(INPUT_DIR)
        hdfs dfs -rm -f -r $(OUTPUT_DIR)
        hdfs dfs -rm -r -f $(EXAMPLE_DIR)
        hdfs dfs -rm -f matrices

    .PHONY: run
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Could you [edit] your question to include an example of running make that demonstrates the problem you are having? And make sure your question includes the version of the makefile which produces the problem.

Comment: @Kenster I would like to put it but it is not related to the code and I have a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be badly confused about how makefiles work. You must start with simoke ones before you attempt complex ones.

If a makefile contains a **rule** like this:

```
foo: bar
    kleb
```

then `foo` is a **target** (usually the name of a file that Make can build). `bar` is another target, and `kleb` is a **command**, which is to be executed by the shell. If you swap `bar` and `kleb`, you will probably get an error, because `kleb` is probably not a target that Make knows how to build, and `bar` is probably not a command the that the shell knows how to execute.

Comment: But it is not like the simple one. The inputs is defined in the make file, which means it include a bunch of commands

Comment: @Anderson: I suspect that you are using the same name for two different things, and failing to expand a variable. If you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe I can be more specific.